# stopPropagation on jquery on click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I possibly stop propagation on the click of a div that is not created until its parent div is clicked?

HTML

```
<div id = "parent"> Some Stuff </div>
```

Jquery

```
$('#parent').click(function(){
  $(this).append('<div class = 'button'> Button One </div>');
});

$('#parent').on('click', '.button', function(){
   // Do some stuff but stop propagation
});
```

I have to have control over the buttons that are appended to the parent element, but the parent element also has its own events to fire as seen. What can I do to prevent the buttons from firing the parent event if e.stopPropagation cannot be used here?

Comment: Why cannot be used? Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/kzdkny5j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the order in which the `#parent` event handlers are created:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.button', function(){
   return false;
});

$('#parent').click(function(){
    $(this).append('<div class = 'button'> Button One </div>');
});
```

Now the `#parent`'s `.button` event handler will fire before its append event handler does. Returning false from this (the equivalent of e.stopPropagation and e.preventDefault) will stop the 2nd event handler from running.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/78twx044/1/)

Comment: I do not think ordering play a role here. Change the order and works exactly same.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This answer is wrong then. It shouldn't have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you right, you need to stop #parent div click event when the you click .button div to not add more .button div's

you could make a small check if the e.target is .button, then just back out from the #parent click handler

check below example

```
$('#parent').click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).is('.button'))
      return;
  alert('parentClick');
  $(this).append('<div class = "button"> Button One </div>');
});

$('#parent').on('click', '.button', function(){
    alert('buttonClick');
});
```